# UITableViewCell resize to fit detail text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, resize

I am trying to resize a `UITableViewCell` to show/hide parts of the detail text on selection.
All cells show the first line of the detail text. when the user taps a cell, the entire detail text should be displayed without moving the currently visible part of the text.

Currently, I am doing the following:
In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = ...;

if ([indexPath isEqual:self.currentSelection])
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = CGFLOAT_MAX;
}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
}
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([self.currentSelection isEqual:indexPath])
{
    self.currentSelection = nil;
}
else
{
    self.currentSelection = indexPath;
}

[tableView reloadData];
```

And in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
float minHeight = 60;

if ([indexPath isEqual:self.currentSelection])
{
    KPLexiconEntry *lexiconEntry = ...;

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : cellFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};
    CGSize labelSize = [lexiconEntry.explanation boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil].size;

    float height = labelSize.height + 44;
    return height > minHeight ? height : minHeight;
}

return minHeight;
```

This shows or hides the detail text as i wanted to, but the text inside the cell (including the `textLabel.text`) jumps up or down a few pixels.
How can I prevent this and get a smooth appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve this:
Instead of using the `detailLabel`, I created a `NSAttributedString` and used `textLabel.attributedText`. The attributed string simply shows the title (previously in the `textLabel`) in a larger font than the rest (previously ind the `detailLabel`).
I created a method to create the attributed string:

```
- (NSAttributedString*)attributedTextForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    id itemForIndexPath = ...;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

    UIFont *titleFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor], NSFontAttributeName: titleFont};
    NSString *titleRaw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", @"itemForIndexPath.title"];
    NSAttributedString *title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titleRaw attributes:titleAttributes];
    [attrString appendAttributedString:title];

    UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor], NSFontAttributeName: textFont};;
    NSString *textRaw = itemForIndexPath.text;
    if (![indexPath isEqual:self.currentSelection] && textRaw.length >= 30)
    {
        textRaw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", [textRaw substringToIndex:27]];
    }

    NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textRaw attributes:textAttributes];
    [attrString appendAttributedString:text];

    return attrString;
}
```

As you can see, I manually restrict the length of the text for all but the selected cell.

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I assign it like this:

```
cell.textLabel.attributedText = [self attributedTextForIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSAttributedString *text = [self attributedTextForIndexPath:indexPath];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(255, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize size = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil].size;
return ceil(size.height + 22); // adding 22 for padding
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it :-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifire = @"CellIdentifire";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
      [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
    }
    cell.textLable.text= @"";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: where would I put that? Do I still need `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: no you can Put this on CellForRowAtIndex -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifire = @"CellIdentifire";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
      [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
    }
    cell.textLable.text= @"";
    return cell;
}

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I tried to do that, but now it does not resize on selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add height constraint for details text (hiding element) and outlet him. Then set when that element is hidden his constraint == 0;